# Strange behaviour of string comparison in Powershell

Tags: powershell, string-comparison

Consider the following function :

```
function myfunc()
{
  if (condition1) {
    return 'nowork'
  } elseif (condition2) {
    return $false
  } elseif (condition3) {
    return $true
}
```

Now if I call this function, and I know that condition3 is true, I can see that True is returned:

```
...
$result = myfunc
Write-Host $result
```

(this writes True to the console.)

The next statement in the calling function is an if statement to determine what was returned, and act upon that:

```
$result = myfunc
Write-Host $result
if ($result -eq 'nowork') {
  do this..
} elseif ($result -eq $false) {
  do that..
} elseif ($result -eq $true) {
  do something else..
}
```

And this is where it gets strange (to me). Even though I can see that True is returned, the if statement decides to go do 'do this..', the first branch of the if statement, where I would have expected that 'do something else..' would have been done.
Another strange thing is that it sometimes works, sometimes not. I tried changing the if statement to:

```
if ('nowork' -eq $result)
```

and then what went wrong first now worked, but later on the same issue re-appeared.

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my first string comparison, but I can't figure out what. I'm used to writing scripts in Linux (bash), so Powershell must be acting differently.

Btw: script is run in Debian 10, Powershell 7, but the exact same problem also appears on a Windows machine with Powershell 5.0.

Please help..

Comment: `(($result = $true)` -> `($result -eq $true)`, or, better: `($result)`. `=` is only _assignment_ in PowerShell.

Comment: It's a bad idea to make a function return both a string and a boolean depending on your whim, because `if ($string)` is true for any non-empty string, meaning you have to be very careful about how your conditions are written. Unlike Linux shell scripts, PowerShell is based on .NET and all values are typed, so implicit conversions can easily trip you up.  `$true -eq 'nowork'` is *true*. Consider an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum) for this.

Comment: Sorry, typo...
elseif ($result = $true) IS of course elseif ($result -eq $true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You're comparing apples and oranges

PowerShell's comparison operator behavior depends on *type* of the **left-hand side** operand.

When your **lhs** (`$result`) is a `[bool]` (ie. `$true` or `$false`), PowerShell will attempt to convert the **right-hand side** operand to `[bool]` as well before comparing the two.

Converting a *non-empty* string (ie. `'nowork'`) to `[bool]` results in `$true`, so the `if` condition evaluates to `$true -eq $true` -> `$true`.

You can fix this by manually type checking:

```bsh
if($result -is [bool]){
  if($result){
    # was $true
  }
  else {
    # was $false
  }
}
elseif($result -eq 'nowork'){
    # was 'nowork'
}
```

---

The nicer way of solving this however would be to always return the same type of object. In your case where you have 3 different return options, consider an `enum`:

```bsh
enum WorkAmount
{
  None
  Some
  All
}

function myfunc()
{
  if (condition1) {
    return [WorkAmount]::None
  } elseif (condition2) {
    return [WorkAmount]::Some
  } elseif (condition3) {
    return [WorkAmount]::All
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
This made it clear that Powershell is a bit different than other scripting languages. Will have to get used to that....